# Laravel 6, Count number of employees in each department

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4

I'm working on one-to-many relationships in Laravel 6. I have two models: `Department` and `Employee`; two DB tables: `departments (id, name, detail)` and `employees(emp_id, emp_name,...)`.

Below is my code that gives me error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\Users... ")

How do I count and show number of employees in each department?

Blade view:

```
@foreach($departments as $department)
  <h4><strong>{{ $department->name }}</strong></h4>
  <h5>{{ $department->detail }}</h5>

  <ul>
  @foreach($department->person as $employee)
    <li> {{ $employee->emp_id }}</li>
    <li> {{ $employee->emp_name}}</li>
  @endforeach
  </ul>
@endforeach
```

Controller:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Department;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DepartmentController extends Controller {
  public function index()
  {
    $departments = Department::with('employees:emp_id,emp_name')
       ->latest()->paginate(5);

    return view('departments.index', compact('departments'))
      ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
  }
}
```

Models:

```php
<?php

class Department extends Model {
  protected $table = 'departments';
  protected $fillable = ['id', 'name', 'detail'];

  public function employees()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Employee::class);
  }
}

class Employee extends Model {
  protected $table = 'employees';
  protected $fillable = ['dept_id', 'dept_name', 'dept_name'];

  public function employees()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Employee::class);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you tell me what your error is, and which line it's caught in?

Comment: Please check what you get dd($department->toArray()) inside your first loop

Comment: Show image of this data

Comment: share exact line of error, model and controller code.

Comment: can you show the relationship setup from Department to Employee in the Department model and how you are getting `$departments` to pass to the view

Comment: Please, share relationship code and controller code.

Answer (score 1):

You have three problems here:

First, for generating foreign key names Laravel uses singular form of a owner's table name and adds `_id` to it. In your case, for `departments` table it will generate `department_id` and will expect you to have this column in `employees` table.

You should either rename your column in your table, or specify it explicitly in relationships definition:

```php
class Department extends Model {
  // ...
  function employees()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Employee::class, 'dept_id');
  }
}
class Employee extends Model {
  // ...
  function department()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Department::class, 'dept_id');
  }
}
```

Next, when using eager loading specific columns you should [always specify `id` field](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

> When using this feature, you should always include the id column and any relevant foreign key columns in the list of columns you wish to retrieve.

And lastly, your relationship name is `$department->employees`, but in your template you're trying to use `$department->person`. That's the reason the `@foreach` can't iterate over `null` value.

Answer (score -2):

In you controller add

```
use App\Models\Department;
```

then in your show or display function in controller

```
$dept_count= Department::all()->count();
```

then return to view

```
return view('department', compact('dept_count'));
```

you can just call directly this function to display the total number in the department.

```
{{$dept_count}}
```

Comment: Here the requirement is to count no of employees in each department. Your answer will generate no of departments.